# How to create an object with properties from a class which is using 'declare' keyword in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have multiple models which are declared this way:

```
export declare class AnyModel {
  p1: string,
  ...
  pN: number,
}
```

I can not change those class declarations, i.e. I can not add constructors to them in which I give default values to the properties. They are from d.ts files which are representing the server-side models.

Is there a way to instanciate a declared class as it have its properties without setting them manually afterwards? An object which is created this way doesn't posses any declared properties:

```
let obj = new AnyModel();
```

Or at least, is there any way to read the declared class properties dynamically?

Comment: No. Anything with `declare` doesn't exist at runtime. It has no compiled output. It's _only_ compile time type information.

Comment: If you can't change the implementation of the class, and if instances of the class have no properties, then you're stuck.